# CREATE AND DELETE The has_many :through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create and delete reviews

In the model's review I have: `user_id`, `spectacle_id`, `content` and `rating`.

```
# Spectacle.rb
class Spectacle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :reviews
end

# User.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :spectacles, through: :reviews
end

# Review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :spectacle 
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How can I write methods create and delete?

Thank you!

Thank you very much

My preoccupation is: i want to save in model review  at the same time her attributes, user_id and spectacle_id

I do something like this:

def create
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @spectacle = Spectacle.find(params[:id])
    @user.reviews.create(user_id: @user.id)

```
@spectacle.reviews.create(spectacle_id: @spectacle.id)
@review = Review.new(review_params)
if @review.save
  flash[:success] = "Review created!"
  redirect_to :root
else
  render 'home'
end
```

end

and i have some error on my browser:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ReviewsController#create
Couldn't find User without an ID

What is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You can do something like this ..
User.spectacles.build(#attributes)
User.spectacles.create(#attributes)
read ruby on rails .. u will get this thing

Answer (score 0):

You can do `my_user.reviews.build(params).save` or directly `my_user.reviews.create(params)`.

To delete a review, you need to do like this `my_user.reviews.where(myconditions).delete_all` or `my_user.reviews.where(mycondition).first.delete`.

Else, directly from the spectacle it's same: `my_spectacle.reviews.create(params)` etc.

You can find more examples on the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Please look what i do and tell me what is wrong. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just do it in this way: `@review = @spectacle.reviews.build(review_params)`
@review.save
If you do a `create` you can't `save` it (it's already done).

Comment: Please now i have some problem: i want to visualized an spectacle with hers reviews: /spectacle/1/reviews. How can i organize the work. Thank you

Comment: This url `/spectacle/1/reviews` will search all reviews for the spectacle with the id 1. You should implement the `index` method on the `reviews_controller`.

Comment: Thank you! I suppose thant the sql will work like this: select   content, voto
from reviews, spectacles
where spectacle_id = spectacles.id.... Please can you help me to write the method index? Thanks

Comment: It's corret like this: def index(id)
    @reviews = Review.where(spectacle_id: id)
   end

Comment: The request will be like this `select reviews.* from review where spectacle_id = $1..`. You can test your code directly on the Rails terminal (`rails c` on the directory of your project). For the index method you should do like this: `def index @reviews = Spectacle.find(params[:id]).reviews end`